# How can I get rid of Shopping Assistant AdWare on my firefox?

Tags: firefox

I have Ubuntu 14.04 LTS and Firefox 39.0 installed on it.

Recently my Firefox is infected with an Ad-Ware with `"Shopping Assistant"` title on it from `aliexpress.com` website. When I open a shopping website, an unwanted pop-up (internal pop-up not an external frame) opens inside the site.

[image]

I tried many things to remove it but I'm not succeeded. I tried these steps:

- Opt-Out from the ads using the settings of Ad-Ware
- Disable Ad-Ons one by one and restart Firefox (none of them was
  infected)
- Reset Firefox to factory settings and install Add-Ons from the beginning
- Installing `Add Block Plus` ad blocker

How can I remove this Ad-Ware from my Firefox?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problems of this kind are best met with harsh methods.

1. Close firefox completely, check this with

   ```
   pgrep firefox
   ```
2. Delete your personal firefox folder.

   ```
   (pgrep firefox && rm -r ~/mozilla/firefox) || echo "Firefox still running"
   ```

Comment: After a while my Firefox is infected again!!! Is there any way to prevent this type of infection?

Comment: Install an AddBlocker and/or 
uBlock Origin https://addons.mozilla.org/de/firefox/addon/ublock-origin/